# Background switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hi everyone I'm having an issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.

I'm attempting to set and get cookies in the background switcher I'm using. The switcher works well... It iterates through 7 background themes on click and the cookies seem to be working as well, but still on page refresh it reverts back to to the default "theme". I don't think it's a problem with the cookies because according to the alerts I attached to the cookies, it's returning the correct background (in the alert). It's just not loading the correct theme even though the cookie says it is.

I believe I narrowed it down to a bit of code in my javascript that might be responsible for the wrong background, however I don't know how to adjust it to make it do what I want.

The background (on refresh) will be whatever `var current` says it will be. Values of 0-6 will be a new background (on refresh) depending on what value it is. But it doesn't remember the user's selection on refresh. I've tried making var current into an array `var current = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],`, but that didn't seem to help. When I did that it didn't show any of my 7 themes, and only showed the default color in body tag css.

When I tried the array, I changed this:

```
    if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                    ++current;
                    alert($.cookie('style', current, { expires: 365, path: '/' }));
                }
                else {
                    current = 0;
                }
```

to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < current.length; i++){
    if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                        ++current;
                        alert($.cookie('style', current, { expires: 365, path: '/' }));
                    }
                    else {
                        current = 0;
                    }
}
```

This is the click function, but I didn't change anything here

```
$iterate.on( 'click', function() {
            if( isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            nextPage( animcursor);
            ++animcursor;
        } );
```

I'm still pretty inexperienced with javascript so I'm sure there's a better way to do what I'm trying for. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The entire code block:

```
var changeTheme = (function() {
var $main = $( '#bg-main' ),
    $pages = $main.children( 'div.bg-page' ),
    $iterate = $( '#iterateEffects' ),
    animcursor = 1,
    pagesCount = $pages.length,
    current = 0,
    isAnimating = false,
    endCurrPage = false,
    endNextPage = false,
    animEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animation' : 'animationend'
    },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
    // support css animations
    support = Modernizr.cssanimations;

function init() {

    $pages.each( function() {
        var $page = $( this );
        $page.data( 'originalClassList', $page.attr( 'class' ) );
    } );

    $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'bg-page-current' );

    $iterate.on( 'click', function() {
        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        nextPage( animcursor);
        ++animcursor;
    } );
}

function nextPage( animation ) {

    if( isAnimating ) {
        return false;
    }

    isAnimating = true;

    var $currPage = $pages.eq( current );

        if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
            ++current;
            alert($.cookie('style', current, { expires: 365, path: '/' }));
        }
        else {
            current = 0;
        }   

    var $nextPage = $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'bg-page-current' ),
        outClass = '', inClass = '';

        outClass = 'bg-page-scaleDown';
        inClass = 'bg-page-scaleUpDown bg-page-delay300';


        var classes = ['bg-page-0 bg-page-current','bg-page-1 bg-page-current', 'bg-page-2 bg-page-current', 'bg-page-3 bg-page-current', 'bg-page-4 bg-page-current', 'bg-page-5 bg-page-current', 'bg-page-6 bg-page-current'];

    $currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
        $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
        endCurrPage = true;
        if( endNextPage ) {
            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
        }
    } );

    $nextPage.addClass( inClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
        $nextPage.off( animEndEventName );
        endNextPage = true;
        if( endCurrPage ) {
            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
        }
    } );

    if( !support ) {
        onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
    }

}

function onEndAnimation( $outpage, $inpage ) {
    endCurrPage = false;
    endNextPage = false;
    resetPage( $outpage, $inpage );
    isAnimating = false;
}

function resetPage( $outpage, $inpage ) {
    $outpage.attr( 'class', $outpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) );
    $inpage.attr( 'class', $inpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) + ' bg-page-current' );
}

//Cookies
window.onload = function(e) {
  if($.cookie('style') == undefined) { 
      alert($.cookie('style', current, { expires: 365, path: '/' }));
      current = 0;
  } else {
      current = current;
  alert($.cookie('style'));
  }
}
init();
return { init : init };     
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this hits the 'else' portion of the if statement, current is not defined on page load.  I think you'd need do do something like

```
   current = $.cookie('style');
```

Or is it always reporting as undefined on page load?

I'd just of made a comment, but lack of rep points prevents this.

```
    //Cookies
    window.onload = function(e) {
      if($.cookie('style') == undefined) { 
          alert($.cookie('style', current, { expires: 365, path: '/' }));
          current = 0;
      } else {
          current = current;
      alert($.cookie('style'));
      }
    }
```

Comment: On page load it will show any of the values 0-6 depending on which theme I was on last. On first page load it'll alert me that I set a cookie for style=0. I've tried setting `var current` to the cookie but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Soo, after current is set, call the function that sets your background, or make a function that changes the background color to the set value.

Comment: I thought I've been doing that. I've tried setting var current to the value of the cookie, but still nothing new is happening. It seems that the value of `var current` is being updated or at least that's what the cookie is telling me, but the browser is still defaulting to the first background option. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: window.onload = function(e) {}, this happens after the entire page has been loaded, for example, your background.  It's already loaded, meaning after you find in your cookie that the user saved a different background, you then need to 'change the background'.  Use something like $("body.test").css("background-color","red");  instead of red, maybe the value of current.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I made it work! I had to move around a couple of the cookies I was setting into the click function and then call the init function with the value of current. Thanks again for your suggestions!